# Blender 2.8 general frame lag

Tags: performance

With the recent release of Blender 2.80, I was expecting it to be as polished and lag free as 2.79b
I guess I set my expectations a little too high cause I'm disappointed it still feels like it's in beta at ~0.5FPS on the default scene.

Is there anything more I can do to bump up my FPS on a GT 430?
(I will downvote any comments telling me to upgrade)

It's not my GPU that's bad as 2.79b runs well over 50FPS with the default scene...

some things I've done already is:
(1.5FPS -> 0.5FPS) I've lowered the Anti-Aliasing to single pass
(disabling makes no difference in FPS, plus I have a similar setup in 2.79b)
And I've set the texture rendering to strict GLSL.

I'm pretty sure it's not my drivers either as literally everything else I run normally runs perfectly fine >40FPS
Xonotic and RedEclipse are probably the most graphically demanding things I run out of the above statement.

Comment: Are you talking about the default scene with the single Cube? If the frame rate ok in Wireframe and Solid mode? is the issue EEVVEE/lookdev?

Comment: yeah, I should probably have been just a tad more clear on that, sorry about that

Comment: every view mode renders at 0.5FPS, I'm surprized there's no Material view honestly... unless that's "Look Dev"

Comment: It meets the minimum spec https://web.archive.org/web/20180801133917/https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-430/specifications
https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
so I would be tempted to post a bug https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: alright thank you

Comment: bug report submitted https://developer.blender.org/T69751 (I'll answer this question when fixed)